# obfuscation with bouncycastle and LWUIT

Tags: java-me, obfuscation, lwuit, netbeans-7, bouncycastle

I have build an application that using LWUIT for UI and bouncycastle for Hashing and Encryption, and every thing is working fine in the emulator but When I try to test it on real device

1- the application not installed correctly because of bouncycastle library need a high obfuscation level to run on the device without any problem

2- so I have set the obfuscation to high level but that made a lot of problem with LWUIT that can't build in the application

3- so I have decreased the level of obfuscation to 8 and the project build successfully but the UI now is not working probably as no button action applied and so on

4- also the application is not installed successfully because of bouncycastle

I need an urgent help please, what can I do to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully used bouncy castle for a lwuit application, so i do not believe that this should be a problem, but if you are having problems with including the bouncycastle javaME jar, then i suggest you download the source files and copy the required classes only into your own code base, with the appropriate package name along with all dependencies.